# Open a file from a path according to date entered

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import files from a folder which is generated on the date the user specifies.

The path looks something like this:
`\\sample\example_group\xxx_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\APP NAME\` and after the last "\" there is today's date in yyyy/mm/dd format.

The folder name doesn't contain slash. It's the folder structure that is generated every day app\year\month\day so it would look something like this: \APP NAME\2017" & "\" & "myVal1" & "\" & "nyVal" & "\"

I am trying to prompt the user to input the date he's reviewing a report for and then have Excel open that folder.

I have the following code, but it doesn't take the user input into account.

```
Sub ImportFile()
Dim dFile As FileDialog, result As Integer, it As Variant
Dim myDate As String
Dim myval2 As Variant

myval2 = InputBox("Enter today's date in yyyy/mm/dd format")
myDate = Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd")

Set dFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

dFile.InitialFileName = "\\sample\example_group\xxx_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\APP NAME\" & "myval2"

If dFile.Show = -1 Then
    Debug.Print dFile.SelectedItems(1)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How can name contain `/`? It's not allowed by Windows... So you can't possibly have such names. Do you mean filtering based on the date of creation of file (folder)?

Comment: I should have specified, the folder name doesn't contain slash. It's the folder structure that is generated every day app\year\month\day so it would technically look something like this: **\APP NAME\2017" & "\" & "myVal1" & "\" & "nyVal" & "\"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not take the user's input into account, because you pass the variable name `myval2` as a string. Thus, it should be like this:

```
dFile.InitialFileName = "\gional\APP NAME\" & myval2
```

in stead of:

```
dFile.InitialFileName = "\gional\APP NAME\" & "myval2"
```

Comment: Heck yeah this one worked, I ditched the "" and now it uses the variable properly. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

A folder name can't contain a forward slash (`/`) and therefore your approach won't work. I suggest using the format `yyyy-mm-dd` instead.

Comment: Hi yeah, but the folder itself uses \ for the date.

Comment: If it uses a backslash (separate folder for year, month, and day), then you should convert your forward slashes to backslashes. Have a look at the [Replace](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php) function.